# Android read Firebase CheckBox acting weird

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, checkbox

I have the following in the project:

1. `MainActivity`
2. `FirebaseHelper`
3. `CustomAdapter`
4. `Person`
5. `one_line_list_item.xml`

**MainActivity Class**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        //searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        //initialize firebase database
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        helper = new FirebaseHelper(db, this, mListView);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(context, helper.people);
```

**FirebaseHelper Class**

```
public class FirebaseHelper {

    DatabaseReference db;
    Boolean saved;
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView mListView;
    Context c;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db, Context context, ListView mListView) {
        this.db = db;
        this.c = context;
        this.mListView = mListView;
        this.retrieve();
    }

    public ArrayList<Person> retrieve() {
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                people.clear();
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Now get Person Objects and populate our arraylist.
                        Person person = ds.getValue(Person.class);
                        people.add(person);
                    }
                    adapter = new CustomAdapter(c, people);
                    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(people.size());
                                                            mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(people.indexOf(0));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("mTAG", databaseError.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(c, "ERROR " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return people;
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter Class**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Person> people;
    ArrayList<Person> mDataFiltered;
    ArrayList<Integer> selected;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Person> people) {
        this.c = c;
        this.people = people;
        this.mDataFiltered = people;
        selected = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return people.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return people.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.one_line_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        CheckBox cbId = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbid);
        TextView nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView dateTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView descriptionTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        final Person s = (Person) this.getItem(position);

        Log.i(TAG, "" + s.get_id());

        nameTextView.setText(s.getName());
        descriptionTextView.setText(s.getDetails());
        dateTextView.setText(s.getDay() + " " + s.getMonth() + " " + s.getYear());


        if (cbId != null ) {

            if (selected.contains(s.get_id())) {
                cbId.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                cbId.setChecked(false);
            }

            cbId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "" + s.get_id(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(c, s.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG, "convertView.getTag --- " + v.getTag());
                int selected_id = s.get_id();
                if (selected.contains(selected_id)) {
                    selected.remove(selected.indexOf(selected_id));
                    v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.default_color));
                    v.setSelected(false);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "CustomAdapter REMOVED: " + selected_id + " - " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    selected.add(selected_id);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.selected_color));
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "CustomAdapter ADDED: " + selected_id + " - " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Person Class**

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String day;
    private String month;
    private String year;
    private String details;
    private int _id;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getDay() { return day; }
    public void setDay(String day) { this.day = day; }
    public String getMonth() { return month; }
    public void setMonth(String month) { this.month = month; }
    public String getYear() { return year; }
    public void setYear(String year) { this.year = year; }
    public String getDetails() { return details; }
    public void setDetails(String details) { this.details = details; }
    public int get_id() { return _id; }
    public void set_id(int _id) { this._id = _id; }
    public Person() { }
}
```

**one_line_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/cbid"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:lineHeight="18dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/cbid"
        android:lineHeight="12dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/cbid"
        android:lineHeight="18dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/additional_description"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Sorry for this long code, I put only the necessary parts of each `Class` to make it as clear as possible...**

**The issue is:**
When clicking any `checkbox` on the list, it seems to be checking also others that are hidden from the view.
I tried to isolate the issue as possible but can't figure this out...
Any ideas why it would be checking also other items that are hidden from view??
They are checked in intervals of 8 and also unchecked when any of the is unchecked....

**UPDATE:**
Tried implementing this in `MainActivity`:

```
mListView.setLongClickable(true);
selected = new ArrayList<>();
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // int selected_id = s.get_id();
        int selected_id = position;
        if (selected.contains(selected_id)) {
            selected.remove(selected.indexOf(selected_id));
            Log.i(TAG, " -- remove -- " + parent.getChildAt(selected_id));
            parent.getChildAt(selected_id).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.default_color));
            //view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.default_color));
            //view.setSelected(false);
            Toast.makeText(context, "MainAct REMOVED: " + selected_id + " - " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            selected.add(selected_id);
            parent.getChildAt(selected_id).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_color));
            Log.i(TAG, " -- add -- " + parent.getChildAt(selected_id));
            //view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_color));
            //view.setSelected(true);
            Toast.makeText(context, "MainAct ADDED: " + selected_id + " - " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Still no go...:-(

Comment: can you post all the code, and extent the bountry or have you already found a solution?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander I have changed the code to full class code but couldn't find a way to extend bounty, if you know of a way please direct me to it...

Comment: where is the full code of the main class Activity? can you perhaps create a small project and just replicate the problem? upload the project to github or something and I can take a look at it for you. You can just offer the bounty again I think.

Comment: Disclaimer: Haven't touched Android in years. Don't LongItemClick events propagate through the items of a `RecyclerView`/`ListView`? Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689881), it seems here that they are using a custom `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` that makes sure to filter out those that aren't visible. Alternatively, couldn't you compare the `View v` being passed to the event and check if that `View` matches either `convertView` or one of it's children and ignore it if it doesn't? It doesn't seem that the event handler cares if it was actually the item clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try below implementation:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ....

    final Person s = (Person) this.getItem(position);

    if (selected.contains(s.get_id())) {
        cbId.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        cbId.setChecked(false);
    }

    ....

    cbId.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // update your model (or other business logic) based on isChecked

            int selected_id = s.get_id();
            if (selected.contains(selected_id)) {
                selected.remove(selected_id);
                Toast.makeText(c, "REMOVED: " + selected_id + " - " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                selected.add(selected_id);
                Toast.makeText(c, "ADDED: " + selected_id + " - " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    ....

    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c, " -- onLongClick -- " + s.get_id() + " - " + s.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            int selected_id = s.get_id();
            if (selected.contains(selected_id)) {
                selected.remove(selected_id);
            } else {
                selected.add(selected_id);
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

            return false;
        }
    });

    ....
}
```

Comment: @Jadeye, Have you checked that?